# Human-sized bipedal silhouette on the side of SpaceX Starhopper; identifiable SFF character?

Tags: character-identification

**update:** The silhouette now has a page in Wikimedia Commons: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hughmann_for_scale.svg

---

The images below are from a NASA Spaceflight forum [post](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=47120.msg1970940#msg1970940) and can be seen in @bolsachicagal's [twitter](https://twitter.com/bocachicagal?lang=en) and also in this NASASpaceFlight [tweet](https://twitter.com/NASASpaceflight/status/1154764428782592001).

**Question:** Is this human-sized bipedal silhouette on the side of SpaceX Starhopper an identifiable SFF character?

In 2012 SpaceX put a [human-sized figure on its Grasshopper rocket](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/283032287602413568) but in 2019 this figure on the Starhopper rocket has a *distinctly non-human shape*. Knowing Musk's sense of humor and tendency to reference SF in naming one-off crafts (usually the ocean ships) I thought this might be an SF reference as well.

[This comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/37738/what-does-this-humanoid-silhouette-on-spacexs-starhopper-represent#comment120304_37738) under my related but different question [What does this humanoid silhouette on SpaceX's Starhopper represent?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37738/12102) (we're hoping it's not a "kill marking") shows an image (cropped below) that makes it clear the figure is human sized, but it looks more like an action figure to me.

[image]

**above:** cropped and zoomed from below; **below:** from a NASA Spaceflight forum [post](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=47120.msg1970940#msg1970940) and can be seen in @bolsachical's [twitter](https://twitter.com/bocachicagal?lang=en) *Click for full size*

[image: SpaceX Hopper @bolsachicagal] [image: SpaceX Hopper @bolsachicagal]

[image]